# Default admin user in config and other users from database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt, userdetailsservice

I'm using spring boot with spring security and jpa. I would like to have admin user in config and other users in database. The problem is when I added `UserDetailsService`, the admin user from `application.properties` stop working.

`application.properties`:

```
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password={bcrypt}$2a$10$7F7xGm8iuzafFA7RPS8gzeKJm9qNBwtejT4hSuBKXMNlc/4NxOy1G
spring.security.user.roles=admin
```

Spring Security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Qualifier("myUserDetailsService")
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encodePWD());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/uzytkownik/pacjent/rejestracja").anonymous()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("admin")
                .and().formLogin().permitAll()
                ;


    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encodePWD() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any configuration Spring Security reads user from properties file by default. But if you add an `UserDetailsService` it means you want to read users using the interface's method `loadUserByUsername`. This method can be implemented for example to read users from database

If you want your admin user from `application.properties` to be considered as a user, you can create it in your implementation of `UserDetailsService` :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Value("${spring.security.user.name}")
    private String adminUserName;

    @Value("${spring.security.user.password}")
    private String adminPassword;

    @Value("${spring.security.user.roles}")
    private String adminRole;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if(username.equals(adminPassword)) {
            return User.builder().username(adminUserName).password(adminPassword).roles(adminRole).build();
        }

        //return your other users from database here
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I change condition on `if(userName.equals("admin"))` and delete `{bcrypt}` prefix in 
 `application.properties ` and it works fine! Thanks for help.